# Anyone have a good web dev work flow they recommend?

Tags: ide, workflow

Hey all, does anyone have a good work flow they recommend? I'm pretty new to web dev and using css, php, html, javascript, and mysql databases.

I'm looking for something along the lines of an IDE/plugins, ability to browse/modify databases would be great too!

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

`sh` is my ide. You can do anything from there:

- Edit files with `vim` or `emacs`
- Edit/view databases with the native db console
- Debug applications using the language debugger
- Use version control (with `git` or some other SCM, preferably distributed)

Comment: Lol. I was hoping for something a bit more gui oriented,but yeah - this definitely would work.

Answer (score 3):

Another great IDE is [NetBeans](http://netbeans.org/features/php/index.html) which should fit all your needs:

- Source code editor for PHP, HTML, JavaScript, CSS
- MySQL integration
- Support for version control like [Subversion](http://subversion.apache.org/)
- and much more...

Answer (score 1):

You might try Eclipse for the IDE using plugins to suite your needs.

Answer (score 1):

A good syntax highlighting code-editor is a huge help.

I do most of my development using:

1. Code/markup: [PSPad](http://www.pspad.com) (Includes fully
   configurable syntax highlighting and limited intellisense for
   multiple languages and project structure support)
2. FTP:  [Filezilla](http://filezilla-project.org/)
3. Database: PhpMyAdmin(MySql) or SQL
   Server Management Studio/Express(SQL
   Server)

Answer (score 1):

[Coda](http://www.panic.com/coda/) does many important things very well, all in a single window.

Answer (score 1):

To re-use much of [my answer to a different question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2885296/how-to-restrict-code-from-developers/2885326#2885326):

I use the [NetBeans IDE](http://netbeans.org/) for editing PHP, HTML and CSS, and I keep all project files in a  [Subversion](http://subversion.tigris.org/) repo. I implement [strict access controls](http://davidwinter.me.uk/articles/2006/03/03/access-control-for-subversion-with-apache2-and-authz/) for any other developers accessing projects, especially if they are consultants outside my company.This way I can prevent developers from changing (or even reading) parts of the source tree they're not authorized to and everyone working on the project can easily merge changes in with the work they are doing.

[Trac](http://trac.edgewall.org/) is a vital part of my workflow as well, as it shows me what in the svn repo was changed, when, and why. Any changes to a project must have a trac ticket explaining what was to be changed, who requested it, and why; every SVN commit must have a trac number associated with it.

What I do is, when code is checked in to the development server using `svn commit`, a working copy on the development server is updated. That way, all testing is done via the webserver running on the development machine, allowing me to grant fine-grained access to developers -- they don't need all they code because they run and test their changes off my server. So the workflow for me is as follows:

1. Check Trac for a ticket describing work to be done
2. Update/Checkout code from svn to make sure I have the latest copy
3. Make changes to code/html/css in NetBeans
4. Commit changes to subversion. Staging site is automatically updated upon commit.
5. Test site off staging server. If more work needs to be done, go to 3.
6. When issue has been resolved, comment in Trac which SVN revisions I believed solved the issue and mark the ticket as ready for review
7. When client/management/etc approves ticket is completed, Trac ticket is closed.

Comment: "Trac is a vital part of my workflow as well, as it shows me what in the svn repo was changed, when, and why. Any changes to a project must have a trac ticket explaining what was to be changed, who requested it, and why; every SVN commit must have a trac number associated with it." Doesn't that mean that SVN is not doing its job?

Comment: @mathepic: What I meant was, I use Trac as my SVN viewer, and also to connect the business side with the development side; bugs/features/etc are entered into trac, often by non-developers. Changes to the code are tracked by SVN, and ensuring that each SVN commit has a trac number means that we can easily see what work was done for each issue.